# Correctly adding constructor in my class

Tags: magento2

I have created a layout processor for checkout field, where I also set the validations for the field:

```
'validation' => ['validate-jurgis' => true],
```

I want `true` to be replaced with a value from my admin config.

As far as I know, you have to use a `__constuct` to get admin values in M2:

```
protected $_scopeConfig;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
```

Then I could call my value like:

```
$value = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('helloworld/general/enable', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

I really don't know much about classes and haven't been able to integrate it correctly.

**How do I correctly add `__construct` to my layout processor so that I could use it in the `afterProcess()` function?**

Full layout processor code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\namespace\Block;


class LayoutProcessor
{
     /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

     public  function afterProcess(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
         array  $jsLayout
     ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Street Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'children' => [
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['validate-jurgis' => true, 'validate-jurgis2' => true, 'validate-jurgis3' => true],
                'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
            ],
            ]

        ];

         return $jsLayout;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented and got the values from admin config in a class:)

```
class LayoutProcessor
{
     /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
     protected $_scopeConfig;
        public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
        {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        }

        public function housenumtruefalse(){
            $var = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('checkoutvalidation/general/housenumberbool', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
            if ($var == 0){return false;}else {return true;}   
        }

     public  function afterProcess(
         \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
         array  $jsLayout
     ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Street Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'children' => [
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['bodymod-validate-housenumber' => $this->housenumtruefalse(), 'bodymod-validate-length' => true, 'bodymod-validate-symbol1' => true],
                'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                'comment' => 'asdf',
            ],
            [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => true,
            ],
            ]

        ];


         return $jsLayout;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dependency injection via constructor in any class. It doesn't matter if it's a plugin, observer, cron, console command and so on. Your approach is correct and recommended by Magento. Do not use Object Manager!

```
protected $scopeConfig;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```